# How do I strip HTML markup or use plain text in the body field?

Tags: views, 8

I am using a view to create a block that display a set of data. The data appears as expected, but it shows HTML markup between body fields, which I want to strip or render as they are like in nodes. I am using hook_views_pre_render(), but I am not able to strip HTML markup with that.

How can I achieve this? Is there any view settings for removing HTML markup?

Comment: @kiablaluno thanks for editing the question but it will be really helpful if you can answer the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using Aggregation (Group Results Together) which caused body field to print the unrendered HTML which is fixed by checking the **Format** option in additional fields to true.

[image]

Comment: This answer may solved your issue but does not seem to answer the question. Maybe the question needs to be rephrased to not mislead other users?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fields in the View, just click on the body field in the View configuration and check “Strip HTML tags”. I believe that’s the name of the option. You don’t need code for that.

Comment: It's not working i.e. I switched to do it using code.

Comment: "Strip HTML tags" would absolutely work, there must be some detail you are leaving out otherwise.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by **some detail** ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the strip HTML tags option in rewrite results
[image: Use the strip HTML tags option in rewrite results]